# How to reshape a 2d numpy array to 3d with variable number of rows per matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I want to train an LSTM neural network and need to reshape a 2-dimensional dataframe / numpy array into a 3-dimensional array for this task. My dataframe has the following structure where it is important to emphasize that each member may have a variable number of rows / transactions:

```
Member   order_day order amount 
a          100         150
a          107         140
a          120         160
b          85          90
b          89          84
c          135         110
```

I now need to transform it into a 3d array with dimensions (# of members, max # of transactions for a single member, # of features) so here (3, 3, 2). The matrices of the members that have fewer than 3 transactions, in this example, need to be pre- or post-sequence padded with an arbitrary number below 0 which can then be masked during training.

The answer to this [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/48796/how-to-feed-lstm-with-different-input-array-sizes/48814#48814) solves part of the problem by showing how a 3d array with variable number of rows per matrix can be padded. It proposes to use the following code where X is the 3d array:

```py
Xpad = np.full((N, max_seq_len, dimension), fill_value=special_value)
for s, x in enumerate(X):
    seq_len = x.shape[0]
    Xpad[s, 0:seq_len, :] = x
```

However, I am unable to figure out how to create the 3d array as a collection of 2d member arrays.

For clarity, the 3d matrix that I am looking for would look like this in case of pre-sequence padding and when -10 is used as the arbitrary negative number:

```
[[100, 150  
  107, 140  
  120, 160],  
 [-10, -10  
  85 , 90  
  89 , 84],  
 [-10, -10  
  -10, -10  
  135, 110]]
```

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: looks like you really need `pandas`.  Its `groupby` function seems to be pretty much what you're looking for.

Comment: Is this data already in a `pandas` `database`?  If it's a `ndarray`, clarify the `dtype`.  Is it already sorted by `member`?